# Multiple Frame Animations with threads Android

Tags: android, animation

I have an activity where I need to display 5 animations in order (when one ends, another starts on the right) First, I tried to use a simple XML file and go from there, but I was getting OutOfMemory errors (I use around 40 png images for each animation).
 I did some research, and I think the only way that I can do it is to use a thread to put the images one by one then release them when they are not needed anymore. The thing is I'm new to Android and I have no idea how to do it.
  I tried to use a class that another guy made available, but it didn't work for me cause I don't know how to control the thread very well (Could make it run for only one animation, or run all five, but on the same spot.. I need to run each animation on a different imageView).

Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

make a custom ImageView by yourself,and rewrite the method onDraw() or draw(),change ImageView when time changed,use method postDelay(...) to refresh,or just postIvalite().